# How to save data to database at fixed intervals on Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm writing a django survey application and it's required to save votes on a queue structure and at 1 minute intervals save the elements of the queue on database. Thats for save I/O overhead.

Currently I'm saving the votes directly from my votes view:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('enqueteapp:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

My problem is that I don't know where I can start the queue and the thread to do what I need to do.

PS: I don't wanna know if there is a better way to do it. I'm required to use the queue stuff.

Comment: I think you can use [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) which is a queue processing system, can use **Asynchronously**

Answer (score 0):

You should be using some kind of cache. Take a look a Django options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/